# Asynchronous execution of commands from two command queues in OpenCL

Tags: asynchronous, opencl

I am trying to work out an application that can utilize both CPU and GPU at the same time by OpenCL. Specifically, I have two kernels, one for CPU executing, and one for GPU. CPU kernel will change the content of one buffer, and GPU will do other things when GPU detects that the buffer has been changed by CPU.

```
__kernel void cpuKernel(__global uint * dst1,const uint size)
{
    uint tid  = get_global_id(0);
    uint size = get_global_size(0);

    while(tid < size)
    {
        atomic_xchg(&dst1[tid],10);

        tid += size;
    }
}

__kernel void gpuKernel(__global uint * dst1, __global uint * dst2, const uint size)
{
    uint tid = get_global_id(0);
    uint size = get_global_size(0);

    while(tid < vectorSize)
    {
        while(dst1[vectorOffset + tid] != 10)
            ;

        dst2[vectorOffset + tid] = dst1[vectorOffset+tid];
        tid += size;
    }
}
```

As shown above, cpuKernel will change each element of dst1 buffer to 10, correspondingly, after GPU detect such changes, it will assign the element value (10) to the same place of another buffer dst2. cpuKernel is queued in command1 which is associated with CPU device, and gpuKernel is queued in command2 which is associated with GPU device, two command queues have been set CL_QUEUE_OUT_OF_ORDER_EXEC_MODE_ENABLE flag.
Then I make two cases:
case 1:

```
clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(command2,gpuKernel);
clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(command1,cpuKernel);
clfinish(command1);
clfinish(command2);
```

case 2:

```
clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(command1,cpuKernel);
clfinish(command1);
clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(command2,gpuKernel);
clfinish(command2);
```

But the results show that the time consumed in two cases are nearly the same, but I expect there will be some overlapping in case 1, but there is not. Can anyone help me? Thanks!

Or, can anyone help to explain how to implement two kernels running on two devices asynchronously in OpenCL?

Answer (score 0):

You are asking too much. As you have probably noticed, buffer objects are relative to a context, while command queues are related to devices.
If a kernel operates on a buffer object, the corresponding data must be on this device. If you do not transfer it explicitely with clEnqueueWriteBuffer(), OpenCL will do that for you.

Hence, if you modify a buffer object with a kernel on one device (for example the CPU), and just after on another device (for example the GPU), the OpenCL driver will wait for the first kernel to finish, transfer the data, and then run the second kernel.

Comment: thanks, but I have doubt on your points. First, I use zero-copy buffer which is deemed to be seen as one copy both for CPU and GPU, no copy needed, I think. Second, you said the corresponding data must be on that device, but I use AMD Fusion APU, the main memory is shared by CPU and GPU, i.e. there is only one memory phsically. So maybe I should ask in another way: for  AMD Fusion APU, buffers in zero-copy area is always consistent among  CPU and GPU or whether the OpenCL implementation will make two copies of this buffer and make it consistent after certain synchronization point?

Comment: Ok, I did not know that you use AMD Fusion APU. My answer was based on my experience with an nvidia gpu and opencl implementation. I have no experience with AMD Fusion.
However, your OpenCL implementation may not allow two different command queues to access simultaneously the same buffer. Maybe you can test that by using two different buffers (although it defeats your purpose).